# df[['a', 'b']].corr() works but df['a'].corr(df['b']) not. why?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

As the title, both cases work well mostly.

But sometimes only second one fail with result 'nan' like below.

[image: example of above]

Are they different method? I'm afraid I cannot provide full background datas. But if someone know about this situation, please give me a clue.

Thanks in advance.

**(add1)**

stdCst.info() below.

[image: stdCst.info()]

**(add2)**

stdCst[[10,12]].corr() works fine, stdCst[10].corr(stdCst[12]) got error, stdCst[[10]].corr(stdCst[[12]]) got error too as below.

[image: stdCst[[10]].corr(stdCst[[12]]) error]

Nice clue but still have no idea. Because I'm not expert of pandas internal structure. Any idea about this?

Comment: What is the shape and dtypes of `stdCst`? Please post `stdCst.info()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the suspicious spaces that you have in the columns naming.

Can you try the following?

```
stdCst[[10,12]].corr()
```

and

```
stdCst[10].corr(stdCst[12])
```